# Sum of each table and Sum of Individual table

Tags: mysql, count, sum

I have two table and i want to find sum of both tables records and sum of each also.Here is my query which give me sum of both correctly.

```
select sum(tot_live) as tot_live 
        from ( select count(id) as tot_live from crm_rentals where status = 2 and is_active=1 and is_archive=0
       union
       select count(id) as tot_live from crm_sales where status = 2 and is_active=1 and is_archive=0 ) s
```

This give me tot_live = 300

Now i want to show count of each like 300=100 and 200

```
tot_live | table1   |table2
300        100        200
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try somethine like below:

```
select @table1:=( select count(id) as tot_live from crm_rentals where status = 2 and is_active=1 and is_archive=0),
@table2:=(select count(id) as tot_live from crm_sales where status = 2 and is_active=1 and is_archive=0 ), 
 (@table1 +@table2) as tot_live
```

Created [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2581/20365) with sample values

Comment: This is already working for tot_live,i need count of each table also

Comment: It give me this issue  Unknown column 'table2' in 'field list'

Comment: @user3244721: upated my post.